# Change ScrollView weight programmatically

Tags: android

I want to change the weight of a ScrollView, but i can't find the way to do it.

There is my XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/firstScrollView">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

   **other layout..

</ScrollView>
```

From code i can only set the height or the width of the scrollView, what should i write for the weight??

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams scrollParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,height);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollParams);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams scrollParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,2.0f);
 scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollParams);
```

The last option in the `constructor` is the weight

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was that i was trying to use  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.. there is no problem about using LinearLayout.LayoutParams and set it to the ScrollView?

Comment: Because the scrollView seems to not been affected by this LayoutParams, but i'm not sure if there is another my mistake or the LinearLayout.LayoutParams simply doesn't work...

Comment: how is your complete xml?

Comment: I have 4 scrollview like that one in the question into a LinearLayout. Now i've figured that if i write numbers between 0 and 1 in the weight it work, but if i wrote numbers > 1 by code nothing happen. Also if i try to change the weight in the xml the IDE said "Rendering problems: java.lang.NullPointerException". Sorry but i'm new in android, i was used to developer in iOS.

Comment: No problem. Ok, let me understand. What is the behavior you expect? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want an "accordion" style (similar to this: http://turbo.premiumpixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/preview4.jpg). I have 4 section, and i just want to expand 1 when the user touch it...

Comment: I used the ScrollView because i can edit theirs weight, but i don't know if them are the right control to use...  Inside those view i must place some buttons and some images (more complex than the image in the example)

Comment: Oh, now I see why you want to change the weight. Ok, if you want to keep on with this approach , you have to remember that when you update the weight of one ScrollView, you have to update the others too, so the layout can adjust itself or you can change the weightSum of your LinearLayout. But, have you tried [ExpandableList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). It seems to be a better fit for your situation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70804/discussion-between-benetz-and-vinitius).